# How can I find the unit vector from a rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am confused about how to find the unit vector from a rotation matrix.

If $R$ is a $3\times 3$ rotation matrix,

$$R = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5 &  2 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & -0.5 \\ -0.5 &  1.5 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Should I just compute the last column divided by the norm?

For example,

$$\dfrac{\begin{bmatrix}1 & -0.5 & 2\end{bmatrix}}{\sqrt{1^2 + -0.5^2 + 2^2}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say *unit vector from the rotation matrix*, I can only think the vector $\vec{v}$ which we rotate using $R$ and it stays the same:

$$R \cdot \vec{v} = \vec{v}$$

Then, it means finding $\vec{v}$ is finding the eigenvectors of the matrix $R$ such eigenvalue is $\lambda = 1$ cause

$$R \cdot \vec{v} = \vec{v} \Rightarrow \left(R-I\right) \cdot \vec{v} = \vec{0}$$

Unfortunately, your matrix is not a rotation matrix cause:

- The product $R\cdot R^{T}$ must be equal to the identity
  $$R\cdot R^{T} = \begin{bmatrix} 5.25 & 2.5 & 4.75 \\ 2.5 & 5.25 & -0.5 \\ 4.75 & -0.5 &  6.5 \end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &  1 \end{bmatrix} =  I$$
- The determinant of $R$ must be $\pm 1$

$$\det R = -2.625 \ne \pm 1$$

Now, considering that $R$ is a rotation matrix (which is not the case), as [shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), a way you can find $\vec{v}$:

$$R = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix} h-f \\ c-g \\ d-b \end{bmatrix}$$

And then, normalizing it.